# Pythonでエラーが出てしまう: IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 100

Tags: python, 機械学習, numpy, pytorch

下記のプログラムを実行すると、エラーメッセージが出てしまいます。
実装したいこととしては、Aを混同行列として`A[pred[i]][y[i]]`に1を足しこみたいです。

---

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
File "cnnTm.py", line 61, in <module>
    lossT, accT, ncorrectT = cnnL.evaluate(model, XT, YT, bindexT)
  File "cnnL.py", line 57, in evaluate
    print(Y[i],pred[i])
IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 100
```

**ソースコード:**

```py
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import datetime

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

import getdata

PATH_MNIST = './mnist'
PATH_RESULT = 'result_mnist'

### definition of the network
#
class NN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NN, self).__init__()
        Hin1, Win1 = 28, 28
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size = 5)
        Hout1, Wout1 = _output_shape(Hin1, Win1, self.conv1) # 24 x 24
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(self.conv1.out_channels, 64, kernel_size = 5) 
        Hout2, Wout2 = _output_shape(Hout1//2, Wout1//2, self.conv2) # 8 x 8
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * (Hout2//2) * (Wout2//2), 1024) # 64 x 4 x 4
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.fc1.out_features, 10)

    def forward(self, X):
        X = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(X), 2))
        X = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2(X), 2))
        X = X.view(-1, self.fc1.in_features)
        X = F.relu(self.fc1(X))
        X = self.fc2(X)
        return F.log_softmax(X, dim = 1)

def _output_shape(Hin, Win, conv2d):
        Hout = int(np.floor((Hin + 2 * conv2d.padding[0] - conv2d.dilation[0] * (conv2d.kernel_size[0] - 1) - 1) / conv2d.stride[0] + 1))
        Wout = int(np.floor((Win + 2 * conv2d.padding[1] - conv2d.dilation[1] * (conv2d.kernel_size[1] - 1) - 1) / conv2d.stride[1] + 1))
        return Hout, Wout

def evaluate(model, X, Y, bindex):
    A = np.zeros((10,10))
    nbatch = bindex.shape[0]
    loss = 0
    ncorrect = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for ib in range(nbatch):
            ii = np.where(bindex[ib, :])[0]
            output = model(X[ii, ::])
            
            #loss += F.nll_loss(output, Y[ii], size_average=False).item()
            loss += F.nll_loss(output, Y[ii], reduction='sum').item()
            pred = output.max(1, keepdim=True)[1] # argmax of the output #ここで分類結果を求める
            for i in range(nbatch):
                print(Y[i],pred[i])
                A[Y[i]][pred[i]] += 1
            ncorrect += pred.eq(Y[ii].view_as(pred)).sum().item()
            

    loss /= X.shape[0]
    acc = ncorrect / X.shape[0]
    print(A)
    return loss, acc, ncorrect

    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ### device
    #
    use_gpu_if_available = True
    if use_gpu_if_available and torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device('cuda')
    else:
        device = torch.device('cpu')
    print('# using', device)
    
    ### reading and preparing the training data
    #
    data = getdata.Data(PATH_MNIST, nV = 10000)

    D = data.nrow * data.ncol
    K = data.nclass
    datLraw, labL = data.getData('L')
    datL = datLraw.reshape((-1, 1, data.nrow, data.ncol))
    datVraw, labV = data.getData('V')
    datV = datVraw.reshape((-1, 1, data.nrow, data.ncol))
    NV = datV.shape[0]
    NL = datL.shape[0]

    ### to torch.Tensor
    #
    XL = torch.from_numpy(datL.astype(np.float32)).to(device)
    YL = torch.from_numpy(labL).to(device)
    XV = torch.from_numpy(datV.astype(np.float32)).to(device)
    YV = torch.from_numpy(labV).to(device)
    
    ### initializing the network
    #
    Seed = 20
    torch.manual_seed(Seed)
    nn = NN()
    model = nn.to(device)
    print(nn)
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01, momentum = 0.9)
    print(optimizer)

    ### training
    #
    batchsize = 100
    bindexL = getdata.makeBatchIndex(NL, batchsize)
    nbatchL = bindexL.shape[0]
    bindexV = getdata.makeBatchIndex(NV, batchsize)
    nbatchV = bindexV.shape[0]

    nitr = 10001
    nd = 0
    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    for i in range(nitr):

        if (i != 0) and (i % 500 == 0):
            model.eval()  # setting the module in evaluation mode
            lossL, accL, ncorrectL = evaluate(model, XL, YL, bindexL)
            #lossV, accV = evaluate(model, XV, YV, bindexV)
            print('#epoch{}'.format(nd/NL), end = ' 　　')
            print('{:.4f} {:.2f} {}'.format(lossL, accL*100, ncorrectL))
            fnModel = os.path.join(PATH_RESULT, os.path.splitext(sys.argv[0])[0] + 'seed{}-{}'.format(str(Seed),str(int(nd/NL))) + '-params.pickle')
            with open(fnModel, mode = 'wb') as f:
                torch.save(model.state_dict(), f)
        model.train()  # setting the module in training mode
        ib = np.random.randint(0, nbatchL)
        ii = np.where(bindexL[ib, :])[0]
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(XL[ii, :])
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, YL[ii])
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        nd += ii.shape[0]

    print('# elapsed time: ', datetime.datetime.now() - start)
    
    ### saving the model
    #
    fnModel = os.path.join(PATH_RESULT, os.path.splitext(sys.argv[0])[0] + 'seed{}-params.pickle'.format(Seed))
    with open(fnModel, mode = 'wb') as f:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), f)
        print('# The model is saved to ', fnModel)
```

Comment: エラーメッセージ「IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 100」は、要素数100(size 100)の１次元(dimension 0)の配列のインデックスに100を指定するのは範囲外(out of bounds)ですという意味です。
要素数100の配列のインデックスに指定できるのは、０から99までですからね。